# Python email module for human beings

Tags: email, python

Is there an alternative `email` module in Python?

Like `requests` is a "HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings"

Handling unicode mails with the email module from the standard library is no fun.

Comment: @guetti That sounds like "for human beings" is your opinion about the ease of use of the standard email module. But we cannot give you advice based on opinions as input. So please [edit your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/13569/edit) and describe the requirements for the alternative module in measurable terms.

Comment: Seconding Jan, and giving you further hints: Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for what else might either be missing, or otherwise improve your chances for good answers. Thanks!

Comment: @JanDoggen: I'm not sure how you interpreted "for human beings" as OP's description of the standard `email` module. He's using the catchphrase from [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which is an improvement over standard Python modules. I'm totally new here, so I don't quite know what level of subjectiveness is acceptable, but it sounds to me as though OP is after something that is of a similar level of abstraction and ease of use as `requests`, but for e-mail instead of HTTP.

Comment: I wrote "Handling unicode mails with the email module from the standard library is no fun.". I am not a native speaker. For me this is a requirement. Have you ever handled unicode with the python email module? If not, please comment on different questions.

Comment: @john I should've said the NOT easy of use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [pyzmail](http://www.magiksys.net/pyzmail/) - from the examples:

```
import pyzmail

sender=(u'Me', 'me@foo.com')
recipients=[(u'Him', 'him@bar.com'), 'just@me.com']
subject=u'the subject'
text_content=u'Bonjour aux Fran\xe7ais'
prefered_encoding='iso-8859-1'
text_encoding='iso-8859-1'

payload, mail_from, rcpt_to, msg_id=pyzmail.compose_mail(\
        sender, \
        recipients, \
        subject, \
        prefered_encoding, \
        (text_content, text_encoding), \
        html=None, \
        attachments=[('attached content', 'text', 'plain', 'text.txt', \
                      'us-ascii')])
smtp_host='smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port=587
smtp_mode='tls'
smtp_login='my.gmail.addresse@gmail.com'
smtp_password='my.gmail.password'

ret=pyzmail.send_mail(payload, mail_from, rcpt_to, smtp_host, \
        smtp_port=smtp_port, smtp_mode=smtp_mode, \
        smtp_login=smtp_login, smtp_password=smtp_password)

if isinstance(ret, dict):
    if ret:
        print 'failed recipients:', ', '.join(ret.keys())
    else:
        print 'success'
else:
    print 'error:', ret
```

Not quite *SMTP for humans* but maybe getting there!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I searched the web before asking here. Maybe I was blind. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check [envelopes](http://tomekwojcik.github.io/envelopes/) as well!

```
from envelopes import Envelope, GMailSMTP

envelope = Envelope(
    from_addr=(u'from@example.com', u'From Example'),
    to_addr=(u'to@example.com', u'To Example'),
    subject=u'Envelopes demo',
    text_body=u"I'm a helicopter!"
)
envelope.add_attachment('/Users/bilbo/Pictures/helicopter.jpg')

# Send the envelope using an ad-hoc connection...
envelope.send('smtp.googlemail.com', login='from@example.com',
              password='password', tls=True)

# Or send the envelope using a shared GMail connection...
gmail = GMailSMTP('from@example.com', 'password')
gmail.send(envelope)
```

**Note**: The documentation says that it should be considered as *beta*. Use with caution.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Development of this projects seems to have staled: https://github.com/tomekwojcik/envelopes/issues/33